# Swift Singleton SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift

I use a separate swift file for my music, it looks like this

```
import AVFoundation


 var menuMusic = AVAudioPlayer()



// Menu Music
func playMenuMusic() {

var menuMusicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MenuBackground", withExtension: "mp3")
menuMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: menuMusicURL, error: nil)
menuMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
menuMusic.prepareToPlay()
menuMusic.play()
}
// Pause
func pauseMenuMusic() {

menuMusic.pause()
}
```

I can call its functions anywhere in my project, like GameScene.swift, by writing pauseMenuMusic()

Now I have seen people doing it the singleton way so it would look like this

```
    import AVFoundation

     class Audio: NSObject {

    var menuMusic = AVAudioPlayer()

    static let shareInstance = Audio() // with swift 1.2 no need for struct and class var anymore

   // Play Menu Music
   func playMenuMusic() {

    var menuMusicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MenuBackground", withExtension: "mp3")
    menuMusic = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: menuMusicURL, error: nil)
    menuMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
    menuMusic.prepareToPlay()
    menuMusic.play()
   }

   // Pause
   func pauseMenuMusic() {

   menuMusic.pause()
   }
```

To call a function from anywhere it now would be Audio.shareInstance.pauseMenuMusic().

Could someone clear me up what the preferred way would be and what the difference exactly is. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase someone has this question, I just ended up using a normal class "AudioPlayers" and than just used static properties and class func for playing, stopping etc the music instead of using a Singleton.